# How to set the "auto scroll" in new version of jCarousel (3.0)?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, autoscroll

How to set the "auto scroll" in new version of jCarousel (3.0)?

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Any kind help would be highly appreicaited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the Autoscroll Plugin. See http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/plugins/autoscroll/